# Why do the two cycloheptadiene isomers both show four distinct shifts in carbon-13 NMR?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

In the following question I have filled in the correct answer for i:

[image]

For ii I thought that should be three for Q and two for P,

For Q there are three distinct enviroments for the C atoms:

- $\ce{-\mathbf{C}H2-{}}$
- $\ce{-\mathbf{C}H2-C=C-{}}$
- $\ce{-\mathbf{C}=C<}$

and for P there are two:

- $\ce{-\mathbf{C}H2-C=C-{}}$
- $\ce{-\mathbf{C}=C<}$

Howevere the correct answer is 4 for both P and Q.

So then I thought maybe they want me to include the splitting of the peaks but in both P and Q there is too much splitting for this to be the case...

Why is the correct answer 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you identified by determining hybridisation and bonding partners weren’t carbons with identical signals but carbons whose signals would appear in a similar *range* of the NMR spectrum. Two atoms will only give identical signals if they are *homotopic* or *enantiotopic* (the latter only in the absence of chiral compounds).

To determine topicity, you first need to determine which elements of symmetry exist in a molecule. Both your cycloheptadienes have the point group $C_\mathrm{2v}$, meaning that there is:

- 1 axis of rotation that transforms the molecule onto itself by rotating $180^\circ$
- 2 perpendicular planes of symmetry
- (and identity, which is always a symmetry operation)

One of the two planes is the paper plane. The second plane interacts with the paper plane where Long’s answer drew a dashed line. The rotation axis is where the two planes intersect, i.e. the dashed line.

With that in hand you can determine topicity. *Homotopic* atoms are those:

- that are transformed onto each other by a rotation which is a symmetry operation for the entire molecule; or
- that can be transformed onto each other by rotation of (a series of) bonds in such a manner that the final shape cannot be distinguished from he original without labelling.

It is the axis of rotation that transforms each carbon of a certain colour onto its counterpart of the same colour. Thus, all carbons of a single colour are homotopic. Homotopic atoms are always *chemically identical* and thus will give a signal with the same chemical shift. Chemically non-identical atoms in similar environments will give similar but not identical shifts.

*Enantiotopic* atoms are those that are transformed onto each other by a plane of symmetry inherent to the molecule. These are only chemically equivalent in achiral environments.

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed 4 carbon environments in both of these molecules, shown below;

A plane of symmetry can be drawn through each, with one environment having only one carbon nucleus. All other sites have 2 carbons.

I don't know that any words will make it any clearer than the picture, but if you aren't sure after looking at this, I can elaborate.
[image]

Comment: I can see how they are different, but I don't understand how it makes the four peaks.

Comment: Each unique generates a different environment. There are four different environments (red, blue, green, purple). Each will have there own signal. The intensities will be 1:2:2:2 (red:blue:green:purple)